# Rendering textured primitives in Android OpenGL ES 2.0 - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I am writing an open-source game engine for Android ([here](https://www.github.com/purpleHack/Schooner-3D)), and I am having a bit of trouble rendering textured triangles. OpenGL doesn't report any errors, but nothing renders. I can render vertex-colored triangles just fine, so I know my VBO- and shader-loading functions work. I have a feeling that I'm just missing some little detail. Here's the relevant code:

```
// loaded is a boolean field 
if(!loaded ){
    int[] tex = { 0 };
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, tex, 0);
    int handle = tex[0];

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    if (useMipmaps) {
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    } else {
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    }
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

    // bmp is an android.graphics.Bitmap object
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
    if (useMipmaps)
        GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    loaded = true;
}

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + glTexture);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle);
GLES20.glUniform1i(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle,
                "s_baseMap"), glTexture);

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                    indexCount, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

The vertex shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform mat4 u_viewProj;
uniform vec3 u_lightColor;

attribute mat4 a_model;
attribute vec4 a_pos;
attribute vec2 a_mtl; // Stores UV coords

varying vec2 v_tc;

void main() {
    gl_Position = (u_viewProj * a_model) * a_pos;
    v_tc = a_mtl;
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_tc;

uniform sampler2D s_baseMap;

void main() {
    vec4 black = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = black + texture2D(s_baseMap, v_tc);
}
```

Comment: have you used `glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);` anywhere?

Comment: `glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);` results in an INVALID_ENUM error, as per [the spec](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml). I'm pretty sure it isn't necessary in GLES 2.0.

Comment: check what values `glGenTextures` is actually producing. If it is giving you some random numbers in the 100,000's then you might want to not use it and have your own system for generating unique texture ID's instead. I had this problem when I converted my app from opengl-ES 1.1 to openGL-es 2.0

Comment: I checked it and it generated 70001. Is that abnormal? Also, not using `glGenTextures` wouldn't cause things like `glBindTextures` to fail?

Comment: When I was using API lvl 7 it would give 1,2,3,n+1 where n is the number of times you've called `glGenTextures`. It was only when I ran my app on a newer device that had a higher API level that I encountered this problem. I don't know the exact specs of GLuint, so maybe 70001 is ok, and something else is failing somewhere else, but if you tried to do multiple textures, you'd rapidly find `glGenTextures` was also a problem. You don't need to use `glGenTextures`, you can just plug your own ID's into `glBindTexture()`. It is just a convenience method so you don't have to keep track of ID's

Comment: @JamesCoote : Okay, I tried using my own IDs, and nothing changed. Any other ideas?

Comment: I edited the frag shader to use black as the default color (see above), and still nothing rendered. I hypothesized that this meant the problem was not related to the texturing. To make sure, I completely removed the `texture2D` call from the shader and made it color every fragment black. Nothing rendered. Now I know the bug is not related to the texturing - I guess I was looking in the wrong place all along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was not in the texturing or frag shader at all. It was in the way the model matrix attribute was loaded to the vertex shader. My matrix loading code was this:

```
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(a_model);
GLES20.glVertexAttrib4fv(a_model, matrix, matrixOffset * 16);
GLES20.glVertexAttrib4fv(a_model, matrix, (matrixOffset * 16) + 4);
GLES20.glVertexAttrib4fv(a_model, matrix, (matrixOffset * 16) + 8);
GLES20.glVertexAttrib4fv(a_model, matrix, (matrixOffset * 16) + 12);
```

Yup, this was part of the "unnecessary" code that I removed in [my second edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8704258/3). *facepalm*

Turns out, `a_model` is the location of the *first row* of the model matrix. Because I was only loading data to the first row, the last three rows of the matrix were empty, so the vertex positions were messed up and the triangles were made degenerate. I fixed this by adding 1 to `a_model` for each successive row, like so:

```
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(a_model);
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(a_model + 1);
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(a_model + 2);
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(a_model + 3);
GLES20.glVertexAttrib4fv(a_model, matrix, matrixIndex * 16);
GLES20.glVertexAttrib4fv(a_model + 1, matrix, (matrixIndex * 16) + 4);
GLES20.glVertexAttrib4fv(a_model + 2, matrix, (matrixIndex * 16) + 8);
GLES20.glVertexAttrib4fv(a_model + 3, matrix, (matrixIndex * 16) + 12);
```

Now it works perfectly!